# How to manually start interactive ksh, and have it execute $HOME/.profile on startup?

Tags: linux, ksh

If I start ksh manually by typing

```
/usr/bin/ksh
```

in bash, then ksh starts in interactive mode. So far so good. But, since it isn't a login shell, it won't execute its $HOME/.profile, which I need it to do. I tried running

```
/usr/bin/ksh $HOME/.profile
```

but then it just executed .profile and exited back to bash, without going into interactive mode. I've tried using the -i flag to force ksh to go into interactive mode, but it doesn't seem to work when I also give it .profile to execute.

I am using ksh93 on Raspian Linux.

Comment: `ksh --login` is generally the way to convince it to run in that manner, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thanks! I was certain I had already tried doing that, but apparently not.

Answer (score 2):

When you want the settings in .profile (or any other shellscript), make sure the file is processed in the current shell, not a subshell. Start the commandline with a dot.

```
. $HOME/.profile
```

This is not a login shell, just an environment with your .profile executed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$HOME/.kshrc` just like `.bashrc` for `Bash`.